# Cannot get relationship_status data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, relationship, facebook-oauth

I'm busy writing an app on facebook, yet whatever i try, i cannot get relationship_status data. My app succesfully gets all the other data it needs (friendslist data like names, gender, profile picture, etc), but not the relationship details.

I have tried to change the rights for the app, so that "user_relationships", "user_relationship_details", "friends_relationships" and "friends_relationship_details" are in the box called "User & Friend Permissions". But whatever i try, when someone wants to access the app, it only asks for the standard data, while in the Preview Auth Dialog it says stuff like "relationship details" etc.

The Graph API explorer also shows that the field is empty or disallowed by the access token for my app.

Regardless of what i try, the JSON data does not contain any relationship_status data..

Did i miss something very basic here?

Comment: Make sure that the test user account has the information filled out and public. I ran into a similar issue, and that was the culprit.

Comment: It doesnt need to be public as long as you have a user_access token.

Answer (score 1):

If it shows fine on the Graph API Explorer, it should work just fine.

The permissions you will need : `user_relationships`,`user_relationship_details`

You can now catch the details from /me and json_decode the data.

Since you say you arent getting any informations, make sure if its present. I mean, if the user_relationships is `single`, there wont be any `user_relationship_details`.

ADD : I just tried and it works just fine.

Comment: Ive rewritten the entire code, starting from scratch, and it works perfectly now. I'm having another issue now for which i will make another thread (since its another issue)..

Comment: If my answer helped anyway, you can rate it. :)